# using blocking APIs with non-blocking server

Tags: python, async

We are using Tornado for our system (behind nginx) -- and everything is working fine.

Now we need to integrate a client lib (for [Neo4j](http://components.neo4j.org/) Graph DB) into our system. The problem is that it is blocking.

My question is:

- is it OK to use blocking libs in non-blocking environment
- what are the possible ramifications if we do so
- how much work is involved if we decide to roll our own async lib

I know there is [Node](http://nodejs.org/) that does everything in non-blocking fashion. But we can't go there because our core is written in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it OK to use blocking libs in non-blocking environment

No. A non-blocking server works because everything is non blocking. The moment you use any blocking code you create a *huge* bottle neck.

Non blocking servers use a single process/thread and an event loop. The moment you block inside the process your blocking the entire HTTP server.

This will not scale.

> how much work is involved if we decide to roll our own async lib

Not that much. Just put the existing library in it's own process then make a thin async API that talks to that process through stdin/stdout.

Comment: typically the server clones itself at startup via fork/exec and runs N instances of the event loop. So technically the entire HTTP server isn't going to be blocked, but close enough

Comment: @Kevin that's implementation specific. I don't know what tornado does. I know node.js doesn't fork/exec itself for you. It will just block the entire HTTP server if your in a `while(true)` loop. Personally I would consider it black magic if my web server forked itself on startup without me telling it to do so.